# Is there any references on the tensor product of presentable (1-)categories?

Tags: reference-request, ct.category-theory, locally-presentable-categories

Is there any references on the tensor product of (locally) presentable categories ?

All I know about this is Lurie's book that deals with the $\infty$-categorical version, and a few references that deals with special cases (Grothendieck abelian categories, toposes etc...)

Is there any references that defines it properly and proves the basic properties ?

Comment: It's certainly not what you have in mind, but I think it might be worth mentioning that Lurie's work does cover this example too (although I don't think he works out the details in his book): $\mathrm{Set}$ is an idempotent algebra in $\mathrm{Pr}^L$ and modules over it are precisely presentable 1-categories.

Comment: Yes of course ! I know. But as you suspected, I was hopping for more elementary references that could also be read by people only familiar with ordinary category theory.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The canonical reference is Chapter 5 of [Greg Bird's thesis](http://maths.mq.edu.au/~street/BirdPhD.pdf).